# Group multiple Google Analytics requests with different time ranges

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I'm building a Wordpress plugin whose job is to calculate how much each published post should be paid depending on how many visits it registers. It relays on Google Analytics.

Now, when a post is published, it takes some time before it can be paid. Specifically, the post is ready to be paid when its visits counting exceeds a pre-set threshold (that we'll imagine is 100, for the sake of these examples). This means that to know when a post is ready the plugin needs to know if it has scored enough visits *since* it was published *to* the current time.

No, suppose we have:

> Post A: published 20/07  
>  Post B: published
>   25/07

The start time for post A in the GA request would be '2013-07-20', but for post B it would be '2013-07-20'. This means that, basically, **every post would need its own request**, which is unbearable both because the plugin pages would take something like 30 seconds to load AND GA would probably ban it soon. The plugin runs on big blogs as well, with thousand of published posts: even if I did some caching, there is still a lot of data that would need to be loaded fresh from GA.

Any help on how this could be sorted out? Thanks.

### Update

After two months, and after Post A and B have already been paid once, we still want to pay the posts that have reached some visits threshold. It wouldn't make sense to ask for *all* the posts of the blog, it would potentially take forever and return a huge amount of data, so we only looking for posts that have, say, more than 1000 visits **since the last payment**. Now here comes the problem: the *last payment date* (which is GA start-date) is not the same for each post. Actually, it is **different** for each post. How would you cope with such a request?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the start and end dates then why don't you just query for that time period and use the ga:pagePath dimension along with the metric you're after (visits, unique visits, or maybe pageviews). Then you can parse the response to get the metric for each post. For example:

```
start-date=2013-07-20
end-date=2013-07-25
dimensions=ga:pagePath
metrics=ga:visits,ga:pageviews
```

(or do unique visits or pageviews if that's what you want)

This will list all page paths during that period with at least 1 visit/pageview.

try the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) to get an idea of the data you want and the equivalent API query.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. As I wrote in my question, each post has a different publication date, thus a different visits-start-date. For post A, the time range would be 20/07-28/07 and for post B 25/07-28/07.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question then. If you query for the period of 20/07 to 28/07, in the scenario you describe, for post B you will get visits from the publication date onwards (e.g. 25/07 - 28/07). This is because there will be no visits data for that pagePath before that date, since it wasn't published.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I simplified because I thought the core of the problem was still there, but we have to go deeper. I updated the question. Thanks.